# PHP script for exporting a single table to SQL file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, create-table

I want to export a single table into an SQL file for backup every day using cron-job.
I've looked around for some scripts bust most were not so user-friendly.

I've seen this: http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/linux-c85098/php-c37728/importing-and-exporting-mysql-databases-using-php-a595887.html

But it exports the whole DB (which weighs about 10GBs), I need to export a single 16mb table.

The preferred method is for it to look like a normal sql file (like the ones Phpmyadmin exports), something like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parts` (
  `flag` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comp` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `hname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change this script and add params for tables name

For example change string

```
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
```

to

```
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' parts > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
```

Where `parts` is your table name

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-database-export.htm

You could either make a bash script, or you could use the exec() php function.

```
<?php

exec('mysqldump -u XXXX -p XXXX [table_name] > [output file]')
```

Comment: I'm guessing "u" is for user and "p" is for password, but shouldn't there be a place to insert the DB itself?

Comment: Yep -u [username] -p [password] and could prepend the table_name with the db for example database_here.table_name_here